# SFTP To Amazon S3 is failing with error "couldn't close file"

Tags: amazon-s3, sftp

I'm copying a file from my local machine to Amazon S3 using SFTP on the command line. The user is configured to use KMS
The connection opens succesfully, and the file transfers, but at the end, I'm getting this error and the transfer fails

the connection is opened, and then cd into the bucket and the file uploaded with these commands

```
sftp <AWS username>@<AWS Host>
cd <s3 bucket name>/<folder>
put myFile.txt
```

The put transfer gets to 100%, but then the following error is logged

```
Uploading myFile.txt to /myS3Bucket/myFolder
myFile.txt      100%  174     4.9KB/s   00:00
Couldn't close file: Permission denied
```

Do you know what could be causing this, and how to resolve it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code that you are using to transfer this file. Indicate specifically where the error is coming from.

Comment: requested details added

Comment: This does not look like a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You simply do not seem to have permissions to upload the file. Can you upload the file using any SFTP GUI client?

Comment: Resolved it with the solution from this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53638402/unable-to-read-or-write-any-files-using-aws-transfer-for-sftp-when-using-kms-enc
The user policy was missing the kms permissions. KMS encryption had recently been enabled on the bucket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it with the solution from this question - [Unable to read or write any files using AWS Transfer for SFTP when using KMS encryption key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53638402/unable-to-read-or-write-any-files-using-aws-transfer-for-sftp-when-using-kms-enc)

The user policy was missing the kms permissions. KMS encryption had recently been enabled on the bucket